# Bean IO Stream Builder Unit Testing using spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have following lines of code that create a `StreamBuilder` for me.

```
@Override
protected StreamBuilder getStreamBuilder() {
   return new StreamBuilder(BEAN_IO_STREAM_NAME)
         .format(FILE_FORMAT)
         .addRecord(FileHeader.class)
         .addRecord(Records.class);
}
```

Now as a part of unit testing, how can I test this method using Spock specification?

Here is my Spock test:

```
def "Get Stream Builder"()
    given:
    StreamBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamBuilder("STREAM").format("fixedlength").addRecord(Header.class).addRecord(Records.class)

    expect:
    streamBuilder == fileProcessor.streamBuilder

}
```

Output:

```
Expected :config: StreamConfig[name=STREAM]
Actual   :config: StreamConfig[name=STREAM]
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to test?

Comment: The invocation of method getStreamBuilder()

Comment: So try to provide a sketch of your test scenario. Might be in spock, may not compile.

Comment: @Opal Added test scenario in the question

Answer (score 0):

Spock's `==` uses `equals` so if `streamBuilder.equals(fileProcessor.streamBuilder)` is false this will not pass.

Furthermore, this test seems to test the wrong thing. Test the outcome not the every step of the way. Otherwise, you get a rigid test that will break for every small refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

To have passed your test you need to implement `equals()` of `StreamBuilder`.

If you don't have or don't want to implement `equals()` the alternative way to verify the configuration is to check it one by one:

```
def "Get Stream Builder"() {
    when:
    def actualStreamBuilder = fileProcessor.streamBuilder

    then:
    actualStreamBuilder.name == BEAN_IO_STREAM_NAME
    actualStreamBuilder.format == FILE_FORMAT
    actualStreamBuilder.records == [FileHeader.class, Records.class]
}
```

Of course, in this case you need to have `getName(), getFormat()`, etc.